# getting React elements offsetTop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in react when I get the offsetTop of the element in the componentDidMount is different than the offsetTop value of the same element when called in componentDidUpdate(). Why is that? I thought componentDidMount is called after render so the DOM elements are placed in the page so the offsetTop value should be correct.

```
class Index extends React.Component {
    ...
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="site-wrapper">
                <TopHeader />
                <IntroSection />
            </div>
        );
    }
}


class TopHeader extends React.Component {
    ...
    componentDidMount() {
        var rect = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).offsetTop;
        console.log(rect);
    }
}


class IntroSection extends React.Component {
    ...
    componentDidMount() {
        var rect = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).offsetTop;
        console.log(rect);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`componentDidMount` is called once and only one . However, `componentDidUpdate` is called for each update that component received , even through state or props.

Then , we recommend to persist the offsetTop in the component state for both lifecycle methods .

Comment: Yes I know, I was hoping that I could get the offsetTop of each element only once since they don't change overtime so to include them in `componentDidUpdate` to reduce overhead.